# How to correctly execute the FFmpeg command to get the quality as in video or better quality live stream?

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, http-live-streaming, live-streaming, youtube-livestreaming-api

I have an m3u8 file with 1080p quality, when I retransmit this to Youtube I only get 360p each time, what do I need to change in the request to get full 1080p quality or how do I properly execute cmd?

My Cmd:

> ffmpeg -re -i http://s15.strak.cf/content/stream/films/File.m3u8 -i usr/hls/log.png -filter_complex "overlay=W-w-25:H-h-25" -c:v libx264 -s 1280x720 
>    -b:v 4M -maxrate 6M -crf 21 -preset veryfast -fflags nobuffer -flags low_delay -g 25 -sc_threshold 0 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -strict -2 -flags +global_header -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -bufsize 3000k -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/

Comment: Show complete log.